# checking one checkbox closes all other checkboxes in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, checkbox

To list portfolio items on https://khofstadter.info/ I use the idea for collapsible checkboxes from https://bernholdtech.blogspot.com/2013/04/very-simple-pure-css-collapsible-list.html.

How can I uncheck an active/open checkbox by checking another checkbox? I.e. I would like to make sure that only one checkbox is open all the time.

I've tried to use the solutions in related posts on Stackoverflow.

CSS

```
.collapsibleList li > input + * {
 display: none;
}

.collapsibleList li > input:checked + * {
 display: block;
}

.collapsibleList li > input {
 display: none;
}

.collapsibleList label {
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

HTML code

```
<ul class="collapsibleList">
 <li>
  <label for="mylist-node1">Click to open list 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="mylist-node1" />
  <ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li>
  <label for="mylist-node2">Click to open list 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="mylist-node2" />
  <ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I would ideally like to remain in CSS and HTML, but can go for JS if needed.

Thanks! k

Comment: Radio buttons...not checkboxes. Or Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior OP described is that of a group of `<input type='radio'>` that share the same `[name]` attribute -- only one radio button can be checked.

Adding `visibility:collapse/visible` `max-height:0/(large number)px`, `transition` to the `<li>` and `overflow:hidden` to `<ul>` makes the lists collapsing/expanding animated. Also pseudo-element `::after`, CSS function `attr()`, and `data-idx` were used so that the text of each label toggled the text "open/close".

The JavaScript and added `<form>` tag allows a radio button to be toggled like a checkbox. Now both behaviors are implemented, details are commented in demo.

```js
// Register the first <form> to click event callback is chx()
document.forms[0].onclick = chx;

/*
//A Pass the Event Object
//B Reference the clicked tag's (e.target) preceding  
    adjacent sibling tag (radio button before clicked
    label (e.target))
//C if the clicked tag is a <label>...
//D and if the radio button occuring before the clicked
    label is checked... 
//E -- uncheck it...
//F otherwise check it
*/
function chx(e) { //A
  const node = e.target.previousElementSibling; //B
  if (e.target.matches('label')) { //C
    if (node.checked) { //D
      node.checked = false; //E
    } else {
      node.checked = true; //F
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
.node {
  display: none
}

label {
  cursor: pointer
}

ul {
  overflow: hidden
}

.node+label::after {
  content: ' open list 'attr(data-idx);
}

.node+label+ul li {
  visibility: collapse;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: 1s;
}

.node:checked+label::after {
  content: ' close list 'attr(data-idx);
}

.node:checked+label+ul li {
  visibility: visible;
  max-height: 500px;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit='return false'>
  <ul class="lists">
    <li>
      <input id="node1" name='node' class='node' type="radio">
      <label for="node1" data-idx='1'>Click to</label>
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="node2" name='node' class='node' type="radio">
      <label for="node2" data-idx='2'>Click to</label>
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks zer00ne. 
I have added it to the Jekyll code (https://khofstadter.info/) that has some for loops and it all seems to work. I'll experiment a bit and maybe come back with some questions. 
many thanks! k

Comment: That's great, I'll be happy to answer your questions as long as they are within the scope of this post. If you have a question that's not related to this post or if it's too complex then you'll need to post a new question which I'll be happy to answer as well. Either way just leave a comment here.